# Copy range of cells after IF and paste to column "J".....Not entire row. VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in VBA:

```
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C").Value = "DOG" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "TOY" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TOYS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C").Value = "CAT" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "TOY" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TOYS").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
```

Instead of selecting just column "A" I would like to know if there is a simple way of selecting columns "A to H".

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: First Filter on `Dog` and then copy to col A. Then filter on `Cat` and then copy to J and so on so forth. [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Copy` to:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A"),Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H")).Copy
```

To reduce the number of times you need to include the worksheet reference, you can use `With ... End With`:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(i, "A"),.Cells(i, "H")).Copy
End With
```

Note that there is a full stop before each `Cells` method.